# Postgres VACUUM and replication

Tags: postgresql, synchronization

I have a master postgres with 2 async replication slaves

I run `VACUUM FULL VERBOSE ANALYSE my_table` on all tables, after vacuuming the slaves get out of sync.
My application reads from slaves, currently everything is wrong!

1. How can I force to sync or run re-sync ?
2. Whats problem here? Why running vacuum issued a problem?!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Whats problem here?

Your server log files can probably answer that much more accurately than random strangers without access to your computer can.  What do the log files say?  The replica logs are probably more interesting then the master logs, but check both.

Do you get messages about `requested WAL segment %s has already been removed`?  If so, you will have to recreate your replicas.  (Unless you have a WAL archive someplace which the replicas aren't currently configred to use--but even then, recreating may be faster and easier).

If you are using replication slots, the master should be retaining all the necessary WAL.  In that case the replicas would still be trying to catch up, it might just take them a long time to do so.  Either wait, or re-create them if you think that that will be faster.

> Why running vacuum issued a problem?!

The key here is the FULL.  Doing that basically rewrote your entire database, generating massive amounts of WAL which needs to fetched over the network and then replayed.  The bottleneck could be anything from the network to the CPU to the disk drive.

Don't do VACUUM FULL without a darn good reason.